# Sql Select phone numbers from a many to many table with different types (mobile, home)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, many-to-many

I have a simple table schema:

```
Person: ID, Name
PhoneNumber: ID, Type, Number                    #Type can be 'home' or 'mobile'.
PersonPhoneNumber: ID, Person_ID, PhoneNumber_ID #A join table that connects the
                                                 #person to a phone number.
```

As data I have:

```
Person: 1, "Ed"
PhoneNumber: 1, "home", 1111
PhoneNumber: 2, "mobile", 2222
PersonPhoneNumber: 1, 1 /*(Person_ID)*/, 1 /*(PhoneNumber_ID*/
PersonPhoneNumber: 2, 1 /*(Person_ID)*/, 2 /*(PhoneNumber_ID*/
```

I want to write a view that returns:

```
Name    |Home    |Mobile
-----------------------------
"Ed"     1111     2222
"Joe"    3333     4444
... etc
```

Any tips on how I approach this?

Note: These tables are a snippet from a larger schema which explains why its a many to many and not more simplistic.

Comment: Is it really true that 1) there are only two types, home and mobile and 2) each person can have only one phone number of each type?

Comment: 1) no, there may be many. 2) no a person may have multiple phones of a single type. The view is being created however to support a legacy scheme where a person could only have 0..1 Home PhoneNumber and 0..1 Mobile PhoneNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in a more complicated way if you have multiple numbers or might have more than home/mobile, but for now, if you only have two numbers, then this will work:

```
SELECT Name, HomeNumber.Number AS Home, MobileNumber.Number AS Mobile
FROM Person
    LEFT JOIN PersonPhoneNumber HomeMap
        ON Person.ID = HomeMap.Person_ID
    LEFT JOIN PhoneNumber HomeNumber
        ON HomeMap.PhoneNumber_ID = HomeNumber.ID AND HomeNumber.Type = 'home'
    LEFT JOIN PersonPhoneNumber MobileMap
        ON Person.ID = MobileMap.Person_ID
    LEFT JOIN PhoneNumber MobileNumber
        ON MobileMap.PhoneNumber_ID = MobileNumber.ID AND MobileNumber.Type = 'mobile'
```

BTW, if you dont want people with any numbers, then you can make the `PersonPhoneNumber` mapping a `JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: This matches my needs - Thanks!

Comment: I've been running this sql but I am getting back 2 rows like this: ed,1111,null then ed,null,2222. How can I merge them to one set?

Comment: @ed. I just updated my code. You need to use a new reference to the mapping table. That should work

Answer (score 0):

```
select  p.Name
,       pnh.Number as Home
,       pnm.Number as Mobile
from    Person p
left join 
        PersonPhoneNumber pn
on      pn.Person_ID = p.ID
left join    
        PhoneNumber pnh
on      pnh.ID = pn.PhoneNumber_ID
        and phh.Type = 'home'
left join    
        PhoneNumber pnm
on      pnm.ID = pn.PhoneNumber_ID
        and pnm.Type = 'mobile'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.NAME,
                (SELECT DISTINCT PN1.PH_NUMBER
                   FROM PHONE_NUMBER PN1
                  WHERE PN1.ID = PN.ID
                    AND PN1.TYPE = 'Home') AS HOME,
                (SELECT DISTINCT PN1.PH_NUMBER
                   FROM PHONE_NUMBER PN1
                  WHERE PN1.ID = PN.ID
                    AND PN1.TYPE = 'Mobile') AS MOBILE
  FROM PERSON P, PHONE_NUMBER PN
  ORDER BY P.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
select * from @Person p
left join @PersonPhoneNumber ppn
on p.ID = ppn.PersonID
right join @PhoneNumber pn
on ppn.PhoneNoID = pn.ID
```